Roth Oil Tank Installed Outside
I am looking to replace my almost 30-year-old oil tank. I have 5 foot ceiling in the basement, my house is located on a pond. I would like to replace with a Roth, but it would need to go outside. I have a location that it would not be seen, and the installer assured me that it was not a problem, when they fill the tank, they will include an additive for cold weather. Anyone have their tank installed outside and have issues? I live in Massachusetts it gets cold but usually not for long periods.

I use diesel stored outside for tractors. Diesel/furnace oil are similar and the additive/anti gel works. You are in the tropics compared to me.

If the installer is also the supplier and they "assure" you, they should be willing to put it in writing.
